# copy back database

Tags: c#

i've added my database to my source folder and whenever i launch the program it copies the db in my Debug folder but the modifications don't seem to be copied back in my source folder,over the old DB .

How can i do so automatically  ?

Comment: Use a batch file and a `xcopy` command that copy your file into up directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways:

1. Put an XCopy command in your Pre-Build event (project->Properties->Build Events). But this will only do it each time you do a build, not after the program has run.
2. Add code to your program to "back-up" a database to a path you specify in App.config, where that path is your source folder.
3. Launch your program from a .bat file that copies the DB back to wherever you want when the program exits.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no "after execution" script being called when the application dies and you are returned to Visual Studio (as I assume is the case you are talking about) you can create a pre-build script which checks if the DB in the DEBUG folder is newer than the source, and then copies it back before the building.

This way you will get the changes back, although you would be one version behind.

A better solution is to check that the DB is not copied to the output folder, and reference it with an absolute path instead of a relative one. This way you would always work against your live database. (I assume you are using SQL Express)